# What's the opposite of "at the expense of"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

> They're doing X at the expense of G's lives

implies there's some unfair trade-off happening, focusing on the unfairness of the cost.

Is there a complement to this that focuses on the unfairness of the benefit instead?

Something like,

> They're doing X to the benefit of G's health

but that makes clear the unfairness of the benefit?

Things like "to the advantage of", "in order to siphon for themselves", "to enable the", don't seem right.

Comment: Note that it is much more common to say ["**for** the benefit of G" rather than "**to** the benefit of G"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+the+benefit+of%2Cto+the+benefit+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20benefit%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20the%20benefit%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Not sure, maybe "in G's favor."

Comment: I'm not sure that "at the expense of" does necessarily imply an unfair trade-off. E.g. "I'm going to drive at 90 mph to get there quicker at the expense of fuel economy" merely implies a trade-off.

Comment: Can you explain how doing something beneficial is unfair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Other answers provide good specific answers to the question. However, I believe it's worth noting/answering that the most common phrasing is still to focus on the cost to others, not the benefit, when stating something is unfair. This answer should be taken in the context of the other answers.*

**They're doing X at the expense of Y.**

In the majority of situations, such as newspaper articles, you will not see them writing the benefit of the situation as being unfair. Instead, they will focus on the disadvantage to everybody else.

While it wouldn't be wrong to write:

> They're building new schools in FancyRichArea, to the sole benefit of a small number of elite students.

What you'll tend to see is:

> They're building new schools in FancyRichArea for a small number of elite students, at the expense of existing schools in desperate need of funding across the country.

The general use of these kind of statements is to bring people onto the side of the writer, and get them upset at an apparent injustice. To do this, it is often more effective to write about how the situation affects their readers adversely, and not just write about the unfair benefit given to non-readers.

*Again, I appreciate this does not directly answer the question. But it is information I feel that is important to the context of answers given here, that is not fitting to be given in a comment.*

Answer (score 15):

> They're doing X ***to the unfair advantage of*** G.

Collins:

> **[to one's advantage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-ones-advantage)**
>   *phrase*   If you use or turn something to your advantage, you use it in order to benefit from it, especially when it might be expected to
>   harm or damage you.
>
> The government have not been able to turn today's demonstration to
>   their advantage.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Usage examples:

> [Google search for "to the unfair advantage
>   of"](https://www.google.com/search?q="to+the+unfair+advantage+of"&oq="to+the+unfair+advantage+of")

Comment: Aaha, I guess putting "unfair" in front of it works too

Comment: Especially since "at the expense of" isn't inherently unfair. The example about lives implies unfairness, but if I decide to play a computer game at the expense of catching up on a TV series there isn't really anything about fairness in that, though the phrase is the same.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the phrase **for one's own profit**:

> The social media giant has been publically busted for not holding up its agreement with users to not sell information about its members or allow companies to mine Facebook data **for their own profit**.
>
> Source: [Face the Face, Posted By Babs Delay on April 4, 2018, 11:00 AM](https://www.cityweekly.net/UrbanLiving/archives/2018/04/04/face-the-face)
>
> I think we do need efforts targeting particular companies, agencies or individuals who are corrupt and are horribly worsening the situation **for their own profit**.
>
> Source: [Clearing Hurdle, Children's Lawsuit Puts Federal Government on Trial for Climate Change Inaction, Posted March 14, 2018](http://www.btlonline.org/2018/seg/180323bf-btl-lebel.html)

Comment: I had a similar example originally "to the benefit of X's pockets" but changed it to "health" because "pockets" alone signals unfairness. "own profit" does the same thing. I'm looking for a general predicate that will make it clear that whatever the benefit is (health, safety, etc.) is unfair. But riffing off your answer, one alternative fitting what I want could be: "for the profit of...". E.g. "they're doing X for the profit of G's health".

Comment: To me, **to one's own profit** actually does sound like a phrase that's directly opposite in meaning to the expression **at the expense of someone**. And it can also be used more generically to talk about something that does not necessarily have to do with stuffing one's pockets with money. E.g. *He used the death of his brother for his own profit.*

Comment: It was "at the expensive of someone's X"; so we need a way to capture what one is gaining (Y). "to one's own profit" doesn't give a place to specify Y after "profit" in the same way "at the expensive of someone's X" gives a place to specify X. That's why I think "for the profit of..." might be more workable, since you can specify Y, i.e. "for the profit of one's Y".

Comment: You're most likely right. But it's very difficult to say whether it's going ot work or not without more concrete context.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could slightly re-arrange your example to insert the phrase "one-sided"

> They are doing X, and this is having a one-sided benefit for G's health."

Among the definitions listed for one-sided given by [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/one-sided) are:

- favoring one side; uneven or unfair; prejudiced
- considering or favouring only one side of a matter, problem, etc
- having all the advantage on one side

Notice also the synonym *unilateral*, if you want to go a little more formal.

Comment: Oh that sounds good, so... "they're doing X to one-sidedly benefit G's health" or "to the one-sided benefit of G's health".

Answer (score 2):

Disadvantage

When something is to the advantage of one, it is usually to the disadvantage of the other.

When something is to everyone's advantage, it's progress.

Answer (score 2):

If one wanted to say something Opposite one would do it in such a manner as this.

The president lowered taxes on the wealthy at the expense of public education.

The president reduced public education funds **to profit** the wealthy with tax cuts.

The chef cut the carrots quickly at the cost of additional waste.

The chef created additional waste in order **to save** time cutting carrots.

Generally one does not use "at the _______ of" to designate a benefit, but a detriment, because the structure designates a taking away, where as a benefit or giving would be "to _____". I think in this case you may be trying to imagine an opposite phrase with the words composing the phrase, rather than the meaning of the phrase as a whole. One could imagine such a thing, but it is never really used that way.

Answer (score 2):

Simply using "at our expense" or "at our cost" implies at least that the benefit is unearned.

If you want explicit rather than implied indication of the unfairness of the benefit you could use "slang" but well understood terms such as
"he's getting a free lunch" or
"he's laughing all the way to the bank" or
"no quid pro quo for us"
with suitable rephrasing to fit in with any desired benefit gained.

More formally "to our detriment" or similar.

Also terms such as "a (very) one sided arrangement".

Answer (score 1):

You have options depending on the context.

"They are doing X **to prop up** G." This implies that G would fail somehow in the absence of X.

"They are doing X **to build up** G." This implies that G will do better with X than would be possible without X.

"They are doing X **to advance** G." Usually, this means G is being boosted toward their goals faster than would be possible otherwise.

"They are doing X **to put** G **on the map**." Here, they are pushing G to eminence from a position of obscurity or underperformance.

Note that "at the expense of" doesn't necessarily mean that the relationship is unfair, only that it has a cost. That cost may be fair or unfair. That phrase is often part of an accusation, but the circumstances determine whether the cost/sacrifice is fair.

As an example: I can choose to buy a new car at the expense of missing my long-term savings goals. No one would deny that one thing was sacrificed for another, but no one is cheated by this decision either.